# How to insert a column with a specific value in sql bulk copy

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

I am populating a table with the values in excel using sql bulk copy in c#.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string line = null;
int i = 0;

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"c:\temp\table1.csv"))
{  
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
            string[] data = line.Split(',');
            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                  if (i == 0)
                  {
                  foreach (var item in data)
                  {
                        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
                  }
                  i++;
             }
             DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
             row.ItemArray = data;
             dt.Rows.Add(row);
             }
      }
}


using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConsoleApplication3.Properties.Settings.daasConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
      cn.Open();
      using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
      {
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 0);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 1);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 2);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 3);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 4);
            copy.DestinationTableName = "Censis";
            copy.WriteToServer(dt);
      }
}
```

In the above code, I am inserting the records from excel into the table. But, I have one more column "ProcessID" in the Censis table. For each time run, I need to generate a GUID and populate this column with this.

Can any one help me how to populate the ProcessID column when I do bulk copy as above with a generated GUID for all the rows for that run?

Answer (score 0):

When you do your insert into the database use the function [`newsequentialid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks JonH. But, I found an answer for my problem. I can use something like this. I can add a new DataColumn with a default value to the datatable which I use for bulk copy.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string line = null;
int i = 0;

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"c:\temp\table1.csv"))
{  
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
            string[] data = line.Split(',');
            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                  if (i == 0)
                  {
                  foreach (var item in data)
                  {
                        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
                  }
                  i++;
             }
             DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
             row.ItemArray = data;
             dt.Rows.Add(row);
             }
      }

      DataColumn col = new DataColumn("BatchId", typeof(System.Guid));
      col.DefaultValue = Guid.NewGuid();
      dt.Columns.Add(col);
}


using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConsoleApplication3.Properties.Settings.daasConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
      cn.Open();
      using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
      {
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 0);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 1);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 2);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 3);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 4);
            copy.DestinationTableName = "Censis";
            copy.WriteToServer(dt);
      }
}
```

Comment: using .net to generate a GUID is highly not recommended.  This causes gaps between your data and fragmentation.  It is recommended to use `newsequentialid()`.